# How to bind a child view to parent in React native?

Tags: react-native

**Problem:**

I have created a react native application there I have created a sign in form it looks like this.

[image]

But when I started to type it look like this.

[image]

Send button is coming out of the card when I try to type. How can I fix this issue?

This is my code look.

```
<View style={styles.signInContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.loginFormTitle}>{strings('login.title')}</Text>
        <View style={styles.formContainer}>
          <Formik
            initialValues={{
              mobileNo: '',
              toggle: '',
            }}
            validationSchema={Yup.object({
              mobileNo: Yup.string().required('Mobile number required'),
            })}
            onSubmit={(values, formikActions) => {
              // this._onPress(values);
              setTimeout(() => {
                formikActions.setSubmitting(false);
              }, 500);
            }}>
            {(props) => (
              <View>
                <View>
                  <TextInput
                    style={styles.textField}
                    placeholder={strings('login.mobile')}
                    placeholderTextColor="#bbbbbb"
                    value={props.values.mobileNo}
                    onChange={props.handleChange('mobileNo')}
                    onBlur={props.handleBlur('mobileNo')}
                    keyboardType="numeric"
                  />
                </View>
                {props.touched.mobileNo && props.errors.mobileNo ? (
                  <View style={styles.errorMessage}>
                    <Text style={styles.errorMessageText}>{props.errors.mobileNo}</Text>
                  </View>
                ) : null}
                <View style={styles.togglebuttoncontainer}>
                  <View style={styles.toggleTextView}>
                    <Text style={styles.toggleText}>
                      {strings('login.keep-login')}
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                  <View style={styles.toggleView}>
                    <Switch
                      trackColor={{false: '#dddddd', true: '#c1d6ee'}}
                      thumbColor={{false: '#ffffff', true: '#007aff'}}
                      ios_backgroundColor="#dddddd"
                      // onValueChange={props.handleChange('toggle')}
                      value={props.values.toggle}
                      style={styles.toggle}
                    />
                  </View>
                </View>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.sendButton} onPress="">
                  <Text style={styles.sendButtonText}>
                    {strings('login.button-text')}
                  </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            )}
          </Formik>
        </View>
      </View>
```

This is how I have setup stylings.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  signInContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#f2f2f2',
    flex:0.75,
    // flexDirection: 'column',
    ...elevationShadowStyle(5),
  },
  colempty:{
    flex:0.3,
  },
  signIn: {
    flex: 1,
    // justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  signinView: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#eeeeee',
    flexDirection:'column',
  },
  signinTitleView: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: '5%',
  },
  signinTitle: {
    fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Medium',
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: '300',
    fontStyle: 'normal',
    letterSpacing: 2,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#444444',
  },
  loginFormTitle: {
    fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Medium',
    fontSize: 30,
    fontWeight: '200',
    fontStyle: 'normal',
    letterSpacing: 2,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#444444',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: 30,
  },
  hr: {
    marginTop:-30,
    borderBottomColor: '#c3c3c3',
    borderBottomWidth: 2.0,
    marginRight: 30,
    marginLeft: 30,
  },
  signInBottomContainer: {
    flex:0.1,
    paddingTop:2,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flexDirection:'row',
  },
  signInBottomContainerText: {
    fontFamily:'Montserrat-Medium',
    fontSize:18,
    color:'#444444',
    fontWeight:'500',
  },
  textField: {
    marginTop: 40,
    borderBottomColor: '#cccccc',
    fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Medium',
    borderBottomWidth: 2,
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: '500',
  },
  formContainer: {
    marginRight: 30,
    marginLeft: 30,
  },
  togglebuttoncontainer: {
    flex:1,
    marginTop: 35,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    marginBottom: 35,
  },
  toggleTextView: {
    flex:3,
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },
  toggleView: {
    flex:1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    paddingTop:23,
  },
  toggleText: {
    fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Medium',
    color: '#575757',
    letterSpacing: 2,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: '500',
  },
  sendButton: {
    backgroundColor: '#007aff',
    paddingTop: 15,
    paddingBottom: 15,
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderRadius: 50,
    marginTop:25,
  },
  sendButtonText: {
    fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Medium',
    color: '#ffffff',
    fontWeight: '300',
    fontSize: 18,
    textAlign: 'center',
    letterSpacing: 2,
  },
  toggle: {
    transform: [{scaleX: 1.4}, {scaleY: 1.1}],
    elevation:30,
    shadowColor: 'black',
    shadowOffset: {width: 0, height: 4.5},
    shadowOpacity: 0.3,
    shadowRadius: 4,
    marginTop:15,
  },
  signInBottomLinkView:{
    marginLeft:5,
    borderBottomWidth:2,
    borderBottomColor:'#c3c3c3',
  },
  bottomLinkText:{
    fontFamily:'',
    fontSize:18,
    color:'#484848',
    letterSpacing:2,
  },
  errorMessage:{

  },
  errorMessageText:{
    color:'#ff3d3d',
    fontFamily:'Montserrat-Medium',
    fontSize:18,
    marginTop:10,
  }
});



function elevationShadowStyle(elevation) {
  return {
    elevation,
    shadowColor: 'black',
    shadowOffset: {width: 0, height: 0.5 * elevation},
    shadowOpacity: 0.3,
    shadowRadius: 0.8 * elevation,
  };
}
```

Can someone help me with this problem?.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on how you have set up your styles. If the view has no flex then it won't change dimensions as the touchpad input appears. You need to show how you set up your styles for advice on this.

After seeing your styles, I see you have fixed margins in your styles for heading and text input. The easiest solution is to get rid of these (or keep much smaller ones) and do all your styling with flex and centering components etc. That way they will move according to overall space.